# Fire Validated Event on WinForms ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I have some logic being handled in the `Validated` event on a combobox, but would like it to trigger as soon as a selection is made.  I can handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event separately in order to fire the event, but I'm not sure how to invoke it.

```vb
Private Sub ComboSelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Fire Validated Event
End Sub

Private Sub ComboValidated(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles ComboBox1.Validated
    'Do Something Here
End Sub
```

I'd rather not call into the method handling the validated event directly,

```vb
ComboValidated(Nothing, Nothing)
```

as it's not precisely what I'm trying to do with the code and it will run a second time when in fact the validated event actually does fire upon losing focus.

What code can I execute to fire the validated event (either by fire the event directly or by causing the control to lose focus)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make it as Sub ..

```
Private Sub ComboValidated(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles ComboBox1.Validated

    InCBValidated()

End Sub

Sub InCBValidated()

    'Do Something Here

End Sub
```

So you just call `InCBValidated()`

Comment: `ComboValidated()` already is a sub, one that just has a handler attached to it inline.  That would do mostly the same thing as just calling into the method with null parameters.  I think it's just slightly clearer to call the `Validate` event and then let that fire off and perform any actions that have listeners for that event.

Comment: I'd really like something like the [`OnValidated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onvalidated.aspx) method, but that's protected so I can't call it directly.

Comment: This is only an easy way (may be not too good) to get into **'Do Something Here**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making the control lose focus which then fired all the neccessary events.  The control happened to be in a groupbox so the easiest way to remove focus was just to give that control focus so the same place on the page was still selected

```vb
Private Sub ComboSelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.Focused Then GroupBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```